# Files has Invalid value in c# mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

In my application (c# with mvc4) I have following error when trying to build the project so please any one help me to solve the problem.

> Error 1   Files has invalid value
>   "C:\Users\Sample\Documents\Solution\Solution\project
>   folder\bin\Debug/_HomePage.cshtml", 32, 11, true);". Illegal
>   characters in path.

Comment: This is not i am mentioning Error shown like this and also this is not my current working solution This is the location of my previous solution

Comment: @Abi, delete bin and obj folders from solution and rebuild project

Comment: `/` is not a valid path character. Have you modified your project file by hand perhaps? Search the entire solution for `_HomePage.cshtml` with the `*.*` file filter. Is there a result with `/` prepended or generally funny?

Comment: How was `_HomePage.cshtml` created? The convention is that only layout pages start with `_`. Did you use a custom template or generator perhaps? There may be a problem with the project or generator template

Comment: This is the partial page that why I created like this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pleasse Try "Clean Solution" and "Build Solution"/"Rebuild solution".